# Access state value inside render method in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react. Tried to pass state in constructor into my render method but  My h1 is not visible, any clue what's wrong?

```
class Mod extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
           title : 'Hello world'
        };
       //this worked!
        document.title = this.state.title;
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>{this.title}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Reason is you are defining the title in state, treat state as an `object`, and all the variable that you defined inside that will be the key values, and to access them you have to use it like this: `this.state.variable_name`,  Use this:

```
class Mod extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
           title : 'Hello world'
        };

    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Reason why `document.title='name'` is working is, you are defining it as a global variable, and you can access them any where directly by `document.title`.

[Doc:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document)

> `Document` is an object. The global object `document` represents the `HTML` document which is
>   displayed in the current browser window. The
>   web browser will have JavaScript engine. That engine will provide the
>   developer with some runtime objects, such as `document` and `window`
>   to interact with.

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
class Mod extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
           title : 'Hello world'
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        document.title = this.state.title;
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Change document title in `componentDidMount` - it means it'll be executed when component is ready and visible.

You should not execute browser related actions in constructor as it might be called when there is no browser (eg. when you render your website using node.js server side rendering). `componentDidMount` will be only called when browser (and `document`) is available.

Also you need to use `this.state.title` instead of `this.title`. `this` relates to react component instance, `this.state` relates to state you've set in constructor.

Comment: This is a game of spot-the-difference. Say *what* you changed, and *why*.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get more values from state and those values are to be accessed in jsx many times then you can get like this.

```
class Mod extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
           title : 'Hello world',
           name: "john doe",
           email: "johndoe@gmail.com",
        };

    }

    render() {
        let { title, name, email } = this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <h1>{name}</h1>
                <h1>{email}</h1>

                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <h1>{name}</h1>
                <h1>{email}</h1>

                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <h1>{name}</h1>
                <h1>{email}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```